# memcmp vs direct comparing for word sized struct

Tags: c++

In C++, What is the most efficient way (memory and timing) to compare two structs of word size (eg. size of 4 Bytes in 32 bit architecture). assume no garbage padding bits and:

```
struct A, B;
```

on one hand, I can use

```
memcmp(&A, &B, 4)
```

on the other hand, I can write

```
struct *pA = &A; struct *pB = &B;

if (*pA == *pB)
```

thanks

Comment: You probably shouldn't be bothered, unless you have explicit indication that this comparison is causing a bottle-neck in existing code.  If you do have this indication, it should be trivial to try each and see which is faster.

Comment: Is your question about C or C++? In C++ the comparisons aren't the same. `memcmp` does a byte-wise compare (and is technically C, not C++). Comparing members on the other hand invokes `operator==`, which does whatever it is defined to do (which can be a `memcmp` as well). If it's not defined it is a compiler error.

Comment: if (*pA == *pB)

this is same as if (A == B)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use memcmp or chained equal-to operations when both give the same result?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28858359)

Answer (score 8):

It depends.

It depends on the library and the compiler ... and perhaps the target platform.  If this is a performance bottleneck, the only way to find the most efficient is to write both and compare their efficiency.

If it *isn't* a performance bottleneck (and it won't be), just write the simplest, clearest, easiest to understand code.  Which is:

```
    if (A == B)
```

(not to mention that the above code doesn't have to make any assumptions about padding bits).

Comment: This. Let the compiler do the optimisations. Just write clear, concise C++ code. Abstraction is the entire purpose of the language, so don't fight it. `memcmp` is _almost_ always wrong in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit,  but c++ sturctures has no `operator==` by default!

Comment: so `if (A == B)` just will not compiled

Comment: True.  But neither will `if (*pA == *pB)`.  You need `operator ==` for both (and if you are going to compare for equality *you need `operator ==`*)

Comment: @MartinBonner Ok, I agree.